# All together vs. Altogether

Tags: differences, homophones

Do *all together* and *altogether* mean the same and if not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. "All together" is used to refer to a collection of people or things that are in the same place; for example, "The spoons are all together in the left drawer." "Altogether" means "in sum" or "in total"; for example, "Altogether, the repairs to my car cost $4000."

Comment: +1 Nice. So they have different meanings altogether. :) Altogether here means "completely".

Answer (score 3):

"All together" means everyone or everything together. Where "altogether" is an adverb and means "all in all," "all told," or "completely."

**Examples:**

> It's time to sing. All together now!
>
> That was altogether too difficult.

**Source:** [e Learn English Language](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/difficulties/alltogetheraltogether.html)

**References:**

1. [e Learn English Language](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/difficulties/alltogetheraltogether.html)
2. [Education Bug](http://www.educationbug.org/a/all-together-vs-altogether.html)
3. [LEO Network](http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/altogethervsalltogether.htm)